# How to load fallback font formats with FontFace API

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

When using the FontFace [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace) (not @fontface) is there a convenient way to pass multiple different font formats, like with providing multiple sources in @fontface?

Or alternatively, is there a convenient way to check what formats the browser using the FontFace API will accept, so I can provide the most ideal of several?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what the current draft of the [CSS Font Loading](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-font-loading/) spec says, the FontFace API takes the same values as the corresponding `@font-face` descriptors. It means you can simply pass as the font data source whatever fallback string you’d use in your `@font-face` definition. [It’s how WebKit handles it](https://webkit.org/blog/6643/improved-font-loading/), anyway:

```
let fontFace = new FontFace("MyWebFont", "url('MyWebFont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('MyWebFont.woff') format('woff')");
```

Comment: Updated the answer after double-checking the spec which indeed states pretty clear that the font source argument follows the `@font-face` fallback syntax.

Comment: Well this is unexpectedly straight forward. The Mozilla documentation does a poor job at showing this, and from the spec I would not have guessed this text fallback parameter. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: True, a simple example like the one on the WebKit blog would make the W3C spec a lot more helpful. Now I had to close read the spec in full to notice the parts where they make it explicit that this is indeed the case.